# I am trying to scrape two sets of <p> data: one with <strong> and one without, is there a way to exclude-select?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<div id="column2_A415">
    <h2 class="content_header content_header_yellow"><strong>Date</strong></h2>
    <p><strong>Case</strong></p>
    <p>Summary</p>
    <h2 class="content_header content_header_yellow"><strong>Date</strong></h2>
    <p><strong>Case</strong></p>
    <p>Summary</p>
```

ultimately, I want a dataframe with 2 columns: 'case' and 'summary'. (soup is bs4 ofc)

so far this is what i have:

```
column = soup.find('div', id='column2_A415')
date = column.h2.strong.text
case = column.p.strong.text
summary = ???
```

obviously i will for Loop it after i figure how to extract the *summary* part of the html source code. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use `:has` to specify `p` has `strong` child, then negate that with `:not`, to get those without `strong`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<div id="column2_A415"> 
   <h2 class="content_header content_header_yellow"><strong>Date</strong></h2> 
   <p><strong>Case</strong></p> 
   <p>Summary</p> 
   <h2 class="content_header content_header_yellow"><strong>Date</strong></h2> 
   <p><strong>Case</strong></p> 
   <p>Summary</p>
  </div>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml') # 'html.parser'   
cases = [p.text for p in soup.select('p:has(strong)')]
summaries = [p.text for p in soup.select('p:not(:has(strong))')]
print('cases: ', cases, ' summaries: ', summaries)
```

---

Read about css pseudo classes (`:not, :has`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#pseudo

Comment: incredible!! one last thing: how would you iterate 'Date'? thank you inadvance

Comment: maybe with  `h2:has(strong)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each row always has **two** paragraphs and there are no other paragraphs in the column, you can find all paragraphs and then take the odd and even of them:

```
all_para = [p.text for p in column.findAll('p')]
p1 = all_para[::2]
p2 = all_para[1::2]
```

Now, you have two lists that can be used to construct a DataFrame.

Comment: hi i am new to this, do you mind explaining on your solution ? i dont think i understand. i want to make a distinction in extracting 'Case' and 'Summary'. thanks for your patience

Comment: Since you changed your question, I had to change the answer. See above.